# ¿Como puedo mantener un intercambio de datos cliente y servidor?

Tags: java

El problema que tengo es que trato de enviar un número por un `ObjectOutputStream`, este número se estará incrementando cada vez que se presione un botón, de tal manera que cuando sea `1`, este lo recibirá el servidor(el cual lo recibe correctamente), pero cuando presiono el botón y el numero es 2, este numero no lo recibe, ni los siguientes.

Esto lo envia la clase cliente.

```
    contador++;
    oos.writeObject(contador);
```

Esto recibe la clase servidor.

```
contador = (int) ois.readObject();
```

Luego dependiendo del numero que reciba ejecuta unas condiciones:

```
 if(contador==1){ //instrucciones}
 .
 .
```

Pero como mencioné anteriormente, solo el 1 recibe, los siguientes no.
¿A qué se debe?

Comment: Intenta darle un oos.flush() después de writeObject

Comment: ¿puedes compartir algo mas de código?
la experiencia me dice que hace falta un loop en algún lado pero necesito ver más código para replicarlo en mi maquina